# How change menu item to checked or unchecked?

Tags: c++, winapi

Have menu with some item, need change it to `MF_CHECKED` or  `MF_UNCHECKED`.
And how to check up what item of menu is checked now?

Comment: **1** Read MSDN. **2** read MSDN **3** `DWORD CheckMenuItem(HMENU, UINT, UINT)` **4** Use `BOOL GetMenuItemInfo(HMENU, UINT, BOOL, LPMENUITEMINFO)`

Comment: @enhzflep: From [CheckMenuItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647619.aspx): *"**CheckMenuItem** is available for use in the operating systems specified in the Requirements section. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions. Instead, use [**SetMenuItemInfo**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648001.aspx)."* - You shouldn't suggest using this API without a disclaimer.

Comment: @IInspectable - as I say far too infrequently, thank-you once again. Dilligence with respect to suggesting deprecated interfaces should certainly be higher than mine has been.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keeping the state of the menu in your own variables is the straight-forward solution.  But you can use [GetMenuItemInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the state of a menu item, MENUITEMINFO.fState field.

Answer (score 5):

You can retrieve the check state among other information by calling [`GetMenuItemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647980.aspx). It fills a [`MENUITEMINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647578.aspx) structure. It's `fState` member will have the `MFS_CHECKED` flag set, if the menu item is checked.

To modify the check state of a menu item you call [`SetMenuItemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648001.aspx). There is also a utility function [`CheckMenuItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647619.aspx). The docs state that this API call may not be available in versions after Windows 2000. However, it still is.